# Download and install Skype

Tags: software-installation, skype

I can't install Skype for Ubuntu 12.04. Downloaded from official Skype site, but cant install. All the time same mistake something about i386. What’s wrong?

Comment: Welcome to AU, Olga! If this turn out to not be a duplicate, can you please [edit] your question and include the output of `sudo apt-get install -f`? That should give everybody the necessary information to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a 64-bit version of Ubuntu, you will have to enable [MultiArch](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiArch).

This can be done by running the command

`sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are installing for wrong system.

Confirm if you are running 32 or 64 bit OS and download the installer for the same.